# Understanding for good Android Studio build system

Tags: android

I am developing an app targeting Android 4.4 (API Level 19) and incurred in this annoying [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670).

Basically the appcompat support library references API Level 21 even when running on devices that do not reach that level. In this case my device is running API Level 19.

Since the feature causing the crash is available at API Level 19, if I used appcompat19 I would have no problems. So I decided to try and build my project in a different way... and I noticed that I cannot even imagine what Android Studio is meaning with some terms. I swear I visited the Android web pages, but - as it is often the case - they are very bad (at least for my brain level).

For example, by right-clicking on a module and selecting `Open module settings`, what does this mean?

[image: SDK Version, Build Tools Version]

When I select :

- `Compile Sdk Version` = `API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)` and `Build tools version` = `19.1.0` (as in the figure)

with these settings in the `Flavors` tab:
[image: Flavors tab]

the build fails with plenty of errors, for example:

```
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

pointing to:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionModeCutDrawable">?actionModeCutDrawable</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCopyDrawable">?actionModeCopyDrawable</item>
        <item name="android:actionModePasteDrawable">?actionModePasteDrawable</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeShareDrawable">?actionModeShareDrawable</item>
    </style>
```

**First question: how am I supposed to use the `Compile Sdk Version` \ `Build Tools Version` spinners?** I have both the Level 21 and Level 19 installed, as shown by the `Project` explorer:

[image]

How can I use the settings shown above without incurring in over 100 compilation problems? I cleaned, rebuilt, invalidated caches, I even killed processes, but nothing changes.

**Second question** Since the bug is related to the support library referencing the latest release (21) of the appcompat library, is there any way to:

- build my project using the Level 19 build tools?
- use appcompat-v19 instead of appcompat-v21?
- If I can, where can I find it? The `Android SDK Manager` only shows appcompat v21.

Comment: What happens if you use appcompat 19 and compile with SDK 21?

Comment: I do not know. As I said in the question I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You don't know how to pick 21 instead of 19 in the compile SDK version setting?